# Django REST Framework add a ViewSet as detail on another ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got two models, one of a box and one of box comment:

`class BoxViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Box.objects.all()
        permission_classes = IsAuthenticated,
        serializer_class = BoxSerializer`

`class BoxCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        model = BoxComment
        serializer_class = CommentSerializer
        permission_classes = IsAuthenticated
        def get_queryset(self):
            # this should return a queryset that filters based on the
            # box in the route
            return BoxComment.objects.all()`

If I've set up a router to make Boxes available at `/boxes/` and specific boxes available at `/boxes/{id}/` using
 `router.register(r'boxes', feed.views.BoxViewSet)`
is it possible to make comments available at `/boxes/{id}/comments/`? Or should I just set up a separate route and use GET/POST parameters to refer to specific boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically referred to as nested routers (or nested viewsets), and it's generally not recommended in Django REST Framework. If possible, you should use a flat representation in your APIs, so

```
/boxes/{id}/comments
```

would actually be

```
/comments/?box={id}
```

This is considerably easier to implement with Django REST Framework using [the built-in filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) (and [maybe django-filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)). It's guaranteed not to break in future versions of DRF, and it's the [recommended way at the moment](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/999). The [HTTP API guidelines](https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design#minimize-path-nesting) might be a good read if you're interested why, and there's a [discussion about it](https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design/issues/49) there as well.

---

Now, you can't always avoid using nested routers. I've [written about it in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26916875/359284), using the third-party packages that were available at the time. Since then, [drf-extensions has integrated it](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes) and it contains a decent implementation of nested routers that should work for most cases.

Comment: Okay — that was my other idea. Any reason in particular that nested viewsets are not recommended?

Comment: @WFT I've added a small explanation with a few discussion links about why they are not recommended.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see any problems to do this (I already use it in my projects and everything is fine) - all you need is an url with `box_id` kwarg. This has nothing with "nesting routers", it's just another endpoint with explicit filtering by url kwarg.

```
router.register(r'boxes/(?P<box_id>\d+)/comments', BoxCommentViewSet)
```

Then just filter out corresponding comments in `get_queryset`

```
class BoxCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BoxComment.objects.filter(
            box=self.kwargs['box_id']
        )
```

Comment: I am a novice in Django development, can you please tell me what was get_queryset was used here for ?
won't queryset = Comment.objects.all() be enough own its own.